# Pytorch ValueError: Expected target size (2, 13), got torch.Size([2]) when calling CrossEntropyLoss

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to train a Pytorch LSTM network, but I'm getting `ValueError: Expected target size (2, 13), got torch.Size([2])` when I try to calculate CrossEntropyLoss. I think I need to change the shape somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

Here is my network definition:

```
class LSTM(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers, drop_prob=0.2):
        super(LSTM, self).__init__()

        # network size parameters
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.embedding_dim = embedding_dim


        # the layers of the network
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.embedding_dim, self.hidden_dim, self.n_layers, dropout=drop_prob, batch_first=True)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(drop_prob)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.vocab_size)



    def forward(self, input, hidden):
        # Perform a forward pass of the model on some input and hidden state.
        batch_size = input.size(0)
        print(f'batch_size: {batch_size}')

        print(Input shape: {input.shape}')

        # pass through embeddings layer
        embeddings_out = self.embedding(input)
        print(f'Shape after Embedding: {embeddings_out.shape}')


        # pass through LSTM layers
        lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeddings_out, hidden)
        print(f'Shape after LSTM: {lstm_out.shape}')


        # pass through dropout layer
        dropout_out = self.dropout(lstm_out)
        print(f'Shape after Dropout: {dropout_out.shape}')


        #pass through fully connected layer
        fc_out = self.fc(dropout_out)
        print(f'Shape after FC: {fc_out.shape}')

        # return output and hidden state
        return fc_out, hidden


    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        #Initializes hidden state
        # Create two new tensors `with sizes n_layers x batch_size x hidden_dim,
        # initialized to zero, for hidden state and cell state of LSTM


        hidden = (torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim), torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim))
        return hidden
```

I added comments stating the shape of the network at each spot. My data is in a TensorDataset called training_dataset with two attributes, features and labels. Features has shape torch.Size([97, 3]), and
labels has shape: torch.Size([97]).

This is the code for the network training:

```
# Size parameters
vocab_size = 13
embedding_dim = 256
hidden_dim = 256       
n_layers = 2     

# Training parameters
epochs = 3
learning_rate = 0.001
clip = 1
batch_size = 2


training_loader = DataLoader(training_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, drop_last=True, shuffle=True)

net = LSTM(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, n_layers)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
loss_func = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

net.train()
for e in range(epochs):
    print(f'Epoch {e}')
    print(batch_size)
    hidden = net.init_hidden(batch_size)

    # loops through each batch
    for features, labels in training_loader:

        # resets training history
        hidden = tuple([each.data for each in hidden])
        net.zero_grad()

        # computes gradient of loss from backprop
        output, hidden = net.forward(features, hidden)
        loss = loss_func(output, labels)
        loss.backward()

        # using clipping to avoid exploding gradient
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(net.parameters(), clip)
        optimizer.step()
```

When I try to run the training I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 75, in <module>
    loss = loss_func(output, labels)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 722, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 947, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2422, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2227, in nll_loss
    raise ValueError('Expected target size {}, got {}'.format(
ValueError: Expected target size (2, 13), got torch.Size([2])
```

Also here is the result of the print statements:

```
batch_size: 2
Input shape: torch.Size([2, 3])
Shape after Embedding: torch.Size([2, 3, 256])
Shape after LSTM: torch.Size([2, 3, 256])
Shape after Dropout: torch.Size([2, 3, 256])
Shape after FC: torch.Size([2, 3, 13])
```

There is some kind of shape error happening, but I can't figure out where. Any help would be appreciated. If relevant I'm using Python 3.8.5 and Pytorch 1.6.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone coming across this in the future, I asked this same question on the pytorch forums and got a great answer thanks to ptrblock, found [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/crossentropyloss-valueerror-expected-target-size-2-13-got-torch-size-2/104580/2?u=christian-doucette).

The issue is that my LSTM layer had batch_first=True, which means that it returns the outputs of every member of the input sequence (size of (batch_size, sequence_size, vocab_size)). But, I only want the output of the last member of the input sequence (size of (batch_size, vocab_size).

So, in my forward function, instead of

```
# pass through LSTM layers
lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeddings_out, hidden)
```

it should be

```
# pass through LSTM layers
lstm_out, hidden = self.lstm(embeddings_out, hidden)

# slice lstm_out to just get output of last element of the input sequence
lstm_out = lstm_out[:, -1]
```

This solved the shape issue. The error message was kind of misleading since it said that the target was the wrong shape, when really the output was the wrong shape.

Answer (score 0):

'Expected target size {}, got {}', target size is wrong, check your labels from train_dataloader.

Comment: Hmm. The labels from train_dataloader are just the word ids for the batch, and have shape torch.Size([2]) (as 2 is the batch_size). Is this the right format for using it in CrossEntropyLoss?